# Delay in running Get-ADGroupMember

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Would anybody be able to tell me why the following code block runs so slow with a larger group?  It runs alright when I run it for group with a few members, but when I run in for a group with 640 members, for example, sometimes it runs successfully and sometimes it times out.  The domain controllers are 'local' (i.e. not across a WAN link).  I have tried this from multiple machines and get somewhat consistent (undesirable) results.  Is Get-ADGroupMember supposed to return results quickly for a group with < 1000 members?  I assume it would, however I am scratching my head on this one.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity cri-all_users | measure
$sw.Stop()
$sw.Elapsed
```

Here's an example of my output:

```
Count    : 641
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : 

Ticks             : 2268358861
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Milliseconds      : 835
Minutes           : 3
Seconds           : 46
TotalDays         : 0.00262541534837963
TotalHours        : 0.0630099683611111
TotalMilliseconds : 226835.8861
TotalMinutes      : 3.78059810166667
TotalSeconds      : 226.8358861
```

Here is my $PSVERSIONTABLE

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> echo $PSVERSIONTABLE

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18051
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16628
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

I would appreciate any insight anybody could provide on this.  I've already gone down the road of trying to debug this at the system call level with Process Explorer / Process Monitor and (unsuccessfully) attaching a debugger, but haven't gotten too far.  Thank you so much for your help and for your time.

Comment: I tested it on my domain with a group with 401 users and I only got run-times of about 5 seconds. I don't know what your problem is but I am fairly sure it is not "normal behavior". I would recommend running the diagnostic logs (`Server Manager -> Diagnostics -> Performance -> Data Collector Sets -> System -> Active Directory Diagnostics`) on your Active Directory server and seeing if it is getting overloaded.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Scott.  I would try this but my issue is a little bit more complicated, as I do not have access to the domain controller logs.  I will check the Event log to see if I can find anything there, though.

Comment: I agree with scott, something is off on your domain. On my domain I pulled 807 users in about 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

When it takes 3 minutes to run for 640 members, then the problem is likely not with the domain controller, or the cmdlet itself. Based on your measurements, we are running at about 2.8 users/second which even some of the slowest DC's can handle. You can prove this isn't a problem by running it on a moderate sized group, and if you beat 2.8 users/second, then the problem isn't with the DC. You can also prove it if your CPU isn't being pinned at 100%...

I've seen this problem crop up because of a couple of reasons that you can look into:

- While the groups are iterating, it tries to resolve the SID to an Active Directory object that does not exist. I would check out your Active Directory to make sure that there is no missing or broken AD users/groups.
- This could also be because of a Foreign Security principal that can't get resolved
- While this may not specifically be this case, when you call Get-ADGroupMember with the -Recurse parameter, it may take quite a bit of time to recurse through all your groups.

These issues usually occur when you are iterating through large groups (like Domain Users) where it is more likely to have broken SID's that can cause problems. Each broken SID would cause the Get-ADGroupMember cmdlet to pause while it tries to resolve the SID, wait 10-30sec before it times out, and then carry on.

The fix is to find those bad SID's. A workaround is different method of getting the information, like using the directory searcher:

```
$searchRoot = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$adSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$adSearcher.SearchRoot = $searchRoot

$adSearcher.Filter = "(cn=groupName)"

$adSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member")
$samResult = $adSearcher.FindOne()

if($samResult)
 {
     $adAccount = $samResult.GetDirectoryEntry()
     $groupMembership = $adAccount.Properties["member"]
     $groupMembership | foreach { Write-Host $_ }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, Everyone,
Thank you for your replies.  I have a follow up question regarding this. How would a go about finding a broken SID in this particular group?  I do not see any actual SID entries in dsa.msc; they all appear to resolve via the UI.  Also, they all resolve to a CN via dsget.  At first glance, all of these entries are members of the local domain, so, I am fairly confident that the foreign security problem does not apply here.  Interestingly enough, I can use dsget group and enumerate the members without delay or issue. Also, I am not recursing with -recurse. Thank you again.

Comment: When I had a similar issue, the only way I could see which entry was the problem was to scroll through and look through all the entries looking for anything that was odd or not looking right (direct from the output of the Get-ADGroupMember, as the other methods may not show you what may be wrong). It also could be related to some of the other properties related to the accounts that it returns. If the other methods work better, I would go with those.

Answer (score 1):

I do it simply with standard commandlets, packed in a function to make it recursive. Much faster than get-adgroupmember but doesn't work for "Domain Users" or other primary group membership.

```
function getmember($dn){
    $obj=get-adobject $dn
    if ($obj.objectclass -eq "group"){
        $grp=$obj|get-adgroup -property member
        $grp.member| foreach{ getmember $_ }
    }else{
        $dn
    }
}


$dn=(get-adgroup "Participants").distinguishedname

measure-command {
    $m= getmember $dn
}

measure-command {
    get-adgroupmember $dn -recursive|foreach{$_.distinguishedname}
}
```